# Como crear este Procedimiento en Workbench?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, plsql

Escribir un procedimiento que reciba, como parámetros de entrada, el identificador de un empleado y de un departamento.

**El procedimiento devolverá en un parámetro de salida el número de trabajadores del departamento especificado que ganan más que él.**

Así es como tengo el código de momento pero no se por donde seguir con la subquery para comparar el salario del usuario elegido con la variable idEmp frente a los de su mismo departamento. Las tablas que intervienen las adjunto.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`uemp`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `salarioMasAlto`(IN idEmp INT, idDept VARCHAR(3), OUT param1 INT)
BEGIN 
SELECT count(*) INTO param1 
FROM empleados
WHERE idDepar IN ( SELECT idDepar FROM departamentos WHERE idDepar = idDept);
END
```

[image: Tabla Departamentos]

[image: Tabla Empleados]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo la lógica de tu consulta lo único que te faltaría seria validar el sueldoAnual, que sea mayor a la de tu empleado actual.

```
SELECT count(*) INTO param1 
FROM empleados
WHERE idDepar IN ( SELECT idDepar FROM departamentos WHERE idDepar = idDept)
    and saliarioAnual >(SELECT saliarioAnual  FROM dbo.empleados WHERE idEmp= idEmp );
```

Comment: Algo del segundo select no me cuadra... no puede completar de hacer el procedimiento de forma correcta.

Comment: Ya la edite me falto el campo saliarioAnual, de empleados